# ASP.NET Passing json POST data to Web API Results in null data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

so i'm trying to send data from a textarea to my ApiController and it doesn't seem to work at all.
 this is my ajax ( where value is a string array ):

```
function doCallback(value)
{
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost:83048/api/test/function',
     type: 'POST'
     contentType: "application/json"
     dataType: 'json'
     data:
     { urls : JSON.stringify(value) },
     success......});
 }
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<List<string>> function(List<string> urls)
{
    return await Program.blabla(urls);
}
```

The urls are always null, even though the value passed in the ajax is not ( verified using the debugger )

A little help would be appreciated because i can't seem to figure it out after passing more then an hour on this.

EDIT : I've tried googling more and more and it seems like it is stil returning null ( when stringified ) and nothing when not.
Also, this has been happenning since i've changed the controller into an ApiController, it was working before changing to the Web Api Controller if it can helps.

EDIT 2 : Tried everything in the comments, still nothing working :/

Comment: I presume value is an array of strings. Try just sending values through without stringify. Maybe change controller parameter to string[] too

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson still not working, and i don't think it has to do with value not being a list since it used to be working before i switched to a web api controller...

Comment: You are sending a object from javascript, but the controller is expecting an array. have you tried just 
data: value?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you haven't considered a model here - ie Class A { public string[] Urls {get;set;}} then set it up on client side and before sending it do a Json.stringify?  Still if you need to just pass the list of strings then you not simply concatenate them using a delimiter and send them in as a giant string and split it on your server side.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment value is an array, i can't access my code since my PC is closed but value is an array of all the lines in the textarea, also i did try data: value

Comment: @JS_GodBlessAll value is an array, i forgot to specify

Answer (score 1):

Changing the data to data: JSON.stringify(value) made it work

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'http://localhost:83048/api/test/function',
 type: 'POST'
 contentType: "application/json"
 dataType: 'json'
 data: JSON.stringify(value),
 success......});
 }
```

All that trouble for .. dam it ahah

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify your urls property as array. Meaning instead of passing

```
{ urls : JSON.stringify(value) }
```

Pass like

```
{ urls : [JSON.stringify(value)] }
```

Notice the square brackets.

Comment: value is an array so when you do a json.stringfy it adds the square bracket.

Comment: Yeah..It adds square bracket, but still you get a string value. In console output you will see square brackets because it's a string representation of array. You need to pass actual array object in order to get it properly deserialized into array argument of action method.